# How can I build a PHPUnit assertTag() matcher to match HTML tables like this?

Tags: php, html, phpunit

I'm trying to validate that an HTML table has a given ID, and has 2 rows which each contain 4 cells.

This is the matcher definition I've tried, which as far as I can tell, should work:

```
$matcher = array(
    'tag' => 'table',
    'attributes' => array('id' => 'peopleLarge'),
    'children' => array(
        'count' => 2,
        'only' => array(
            'tag' => 'tr',
            'children' => array(
                'count' => 4,
                'only' => array(
                    'tag' => 'td'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$this->assertTag($matcher, $sOutput);
```

The output that is being tested against is:

```
<table id="peopleLarge">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, this test always fails.

I assume that I'm writing the matcher definition wrong, so could somebody who knows more about PHPUnit than I do give me a helping hand?

The output from PHPUnit is as follows:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed asserting that <boolean:false> is true.
#0 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert.php(2087): fail()
#1 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert.php(756): assertThat()
#2 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert.php(2048): assertTrue()
#3 C:\_company\t\timeforchildren\webroot\tests\app\views\People_View_LargeTest.php(93): assertTag()
#4 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php(738): invokeArgs()
#5 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php(628): runTest()
#6 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php(666): runBare()
#7 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php(576): run()
#8 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php(757): run()
#9 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php(733): runTest()
#10 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php(305): run()
#11 C:\Users\Nils\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_webroot_Nils.php(485): doRun()
#12 C:\Users\Nils\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_webroot_Nils.php(750): runTest()
#13 C:\Users\Nils\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_webroot_Nils.php(853): main()
```

Many thanks,

Comment: What is the failure message? It would help to see the output from PHPUnit.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that helpful: Failed asserting that <boolean:false> is true. Added full output to my question. Is there a way I can get a more detailed failure message?

Comment: That's a bummer. It looks like `assertTag()` does the assertion, gets the boolean result, and passes it off to `assertTrue()` which leaves you with that worthless failure message. You could check out the code for `assertTag()` to see if you can create a matcher yourself and get more detailed information from the object, but I haven't used this assertion before.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the output of assertTag() stinks.

I would recommend breaking this out into multiple assertions and/or tests. I think the reason you're getting an error is that it's getting confused on the **`'count' => 4`** line.

A good technique, I've found, is to build up the `$matcher` array gradually, and when you get an error, that's the problem point. Conversely, you can write the whole thing, then comment it all out and remove comments gradually.

When that particular line is commented, the assertion succeeds. When it's not commented, I get the same error you do.

Here's the weird part: If you put in a value *other* than 4, such as 5, you get a *different* error:

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I think it might be getting confused because you are counting children of children (grandchildren, if you will) when the children count is *itself* > 1. I tried using a value of "8" because technically your HTML contains *8* td's that are children of tr's, but that gave the foreach() error shown.

Suggestions:

1. Break out into multiple assertions and/or tests. Possibly a separate regex-based assertion to confirm the *counts* of the various elements and the hierarchy?
2. Tip, more than a suggestion: it's not necessary to do

   ```
   'attributes' => array('id' => 'peopleLarge'),
   ```

   Instead, you can just do:

   ```
   'id' => 'peopleLarge',
   ```

   (ID is itself a criteria for assertTag())

Answer (score 2):

I usually add a few custom matchers using `xpath`. These custom matchers can have more desccriptive messages.

In your case

```
private function assertHasXpath($xpath, $message = '', $group = 'Other') {
  if (empty($message)) {
    $message = "xpath '{$xpath}' not found.";
  }
  $xpath = $this->xpath($xpath);
  $truthiness = count($xpath) > 0;
  return $this->assertTrue($truthiness, $message, $group);
}

private function assertHasTableWithColumns($amount_columns, $message = '', $group = 'Other') {
  $xpath = "//*//table/tr/td";
  $amount_found = count($this->xpath($xpath))

  if (empty($message)) {
    $message = "No table with {$amount_columns} found. Found {$amount_found}";
  }
  return $this->assertTrue(($amount_found == $amount_columns), $message, $group);
}
```

You can then write very descriptive and readable tests (which is, what tests should be all about).

```
public function testHasTitleWithPeople() {
  $this->drupalGet("people");
  $this->assertHasXpath("//*/h2[@class='title'][contains(text(),'People')]");
  // This pattern is complex enough to warrant its own assertTitleWithContent($content)

}

public function testRendersTable() {
  $this->drupalGet("people");
  $this->assertHasTableWithColumns(4);
}
```